# Unexpected token = in Mocha react tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, babeljs

I test my React components with Mocha, and when I run npm test I got exception

```
SyntaxError: /Users/igunchenko/WorkProjects/Cloud_App/cloud.webapp/cloud.webapp.web/src/main/ui/app/DOM/pages/AdminPanel.js: Unexpected token (18:10)
16 | @connect()
17 | export class AdminPage extends Component {
18 |     state = {
   |           ^
```

In .babelrc i describe presets and plugins for my react app:

```
{
  "presets": [ "es2015", "stage-2", "react"],
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators"]
}
```

But, nothing changes. What I lost in my configs? And how this problem can be solved?

Comment: May be it's the same issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37679530/babel-syntax-error-in-component-definition-react

Comment: Yeah, it's very similar. Install and use `stage-0`.

Comment: @MichaelRasoahaingo yes, it's seems like same issue, but stage-0 not supported decorators

Comment: Decorators has been extracted from stages, you can even add state-x and decorators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try the following. It helped me.
Add this to ".babelrc"

```
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"],
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"],
```

And this to your "package.json" DevDepedencies

```
"babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
```

Then update your project with "npm i"
Hope it'll help.

Comment: Only this works. Answer given below to use "syntax-decorators", "transform-decorators" doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

It should look more like;

```js
export default class AdminPage extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {something: ''};
  }
```

Comment: Good solution, but I have above 50 react components, and this way is not preferred for me

Comment: I didn't even know that state = { would work so I just changed one of my components and it does work. Unit test with jest/enzyme and stage-2 passes. See https://github.com/calitek/ReactPatterns React.15.Common/Buttons.

Comment: I was wrong, stage-2 fails. There is some weird timing issue running these tests. stage-0 works.

Answer (score 0):

You're just applying the transform plugin while leaving out the syntax of decorators. You can do,

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-2", "react"],
  "plugins": ["syntax-decorators", "transform-decorators"]
}
```

or, As of this writing, The "Class and Property Decorators" are in Stage 1. https://github.com/tc39/proposals

So you can use

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-1", "react"]
}
```